# How using Regular Expression to not match a pattern if two words before a certain word is from a negative list

Tags: python, regex, string

Considering the string below:

```py
str = "word1 word2 word3 word4 word5"
```

I would like to match a pattern if word4 is a sample from [sample1, sample2] and word2 not a sample from (sample3, sample4).

Examples:

```py
str1 =  "word1 word2 word3 sample1 word5"   # it matches
str2 =  "word1 sample3 word3 sample1 word5"  # it doesn't match
```

I wrote a regex using "Negative Lookbehind" but I could match just for one word before not two words before.

Thanks if anyone could help.

Comment: Can you add the pattern that you tried to the question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question asks for a code snippet and doesn't show an attempt to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are searching for a regex like this:

```
\w+ \w+(?<!sample3|sample4) \w+ (?:sample1|sample2) \w+
```

If you meet some problems with "fixed pattern length" you can use negative *lookahead* instead of *lookbehind* in this way:

```
\w+ (?!sample3|sample4)\w+ \w+ (?:sample1|sample2) \w+
```

since on lookahead there is no restriction.

[See regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BPvG4F/2)